# Reading date columns for a csv file with Python pandas

Tags: python

I am trying to convert three of my columns (created at, updated_at,recorded_at) into datetime format using python panda. I am using a CSV file and it is given below

```
id      name    created_at updated_at deliverable_type  recorded_at pax
10001   jack    35:21.0      40:05.0    Table               35:20.9 1
10002   mark    42:29.5      42:30.5    Section       9/13/16 11:42 \N
10003   sam     57:29.7      57:30.5    Section       9/13/16 11:57 \N
10004   alex    58:03.7      58:04.7    Section       9/13/16 11:58 \N
10005   jacki   58:43.4      58:46.7    Section       9/13/16 12:00 \N
10006   sunil   08:53.2      08:54.8    Section       9/13/16 12:08 \N
10007   max     26:46.0      26:49.1    Section       9/13/16 12:28 \N
10008   alice   27:24.1      27:26.1    Section       9/13/16 12:27 \N
10009   markus  28:01.0      29:42.7    Table               28:01.0  2
10010   dan     48:40.0      48:45.6    Section       9/13/16 12:50 \N
10011   jill    56:15.7      56:16.5    Section       9/13/16 12:56 \N
10012   amanda  41:54.2      41:55.9    Section       9/13/16 13:41 \N
```

I have tired the to_datetime on one of my columns but it does not seem to work.

```
import pandas as pd
thedate = ['created_at','updated_at','recorded_at']
df = pd.read_csv('TheCV.csv',parse_dates=thedate)
theDF = pd.DataFrame(df)
date_object = pd.to_datetime(theDF['created_at'],format='%H:%M:%S  %p',errors='ignore')   
print(date_object.head())
date_object.to_csv('theccsv.csv')
```

Can someone tell how can i get the 3 columns converted to a datetime formate

This is the result i get after i print it

[image]

Comment: whats the error you get?

Comment: I am not getting an error as such but the values get displayed as it is in the excel sheet for instance the csv has the value 35:21.0 my dataframe will also display the same value

Comment: Don't give a screenshot. Just cut and paste the same number of rows of your csv into your question.

Comment: I have edited my post and place some of the csv data